# Close TCP port 80 and 443 after forking in Django

Tags: python, django, linux, apache2

I am trying to fork() and exec() a new python script process from within a Django app that is running in apache2/WSGI Python.  The new python process is daemonized so that it doesn't hold any association to apache2, but I know the HTTP ports are still open.  The new process kills apache2, but as a result the new python process now holds port 80 and 443 open, and I don't want this.

How do I close port 80 and 443 from within the new python process?  Is there a way to gain access to the socket handle descriptors so they can be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `subprocess` module to execute the script, the `close_fds` argument to the `Popen` constructor will probably do what you want:

> If close_fds is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be closed before the child process is executed.

Assuming they weren't simply closed, the first three file descriptors are traditionally `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, so the listening sockets in the Django application will be among those closed in the child process.

Comment: subprocess.Popen(myProcArgs,close_fds=True,...) worked perfectly.  Many thanks.